# Starting Position for Draggable Widgets in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, drag-and-drop, kivymd

Is there any way that Kivy widgets that inherit from DragBehavior can have a set starting position, but still be draggable? When I set the `pos_hint` attributes of such widgets, they become stationary and are no longer draggable. For instance, the code provided allows the user to drag OneLineListItems (part of the KivyMD framework) using DragBehavior.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior


KV = """

<DragListItem@OneLineListItem+DragBehavior>:
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width * 0.5, self.height * 0.6
    drag_timeout: 1000000
    drag_distance: 0
    size_hint_x: 0.3


FloatLayout:

    DragListItem:
        text: "Test Item 1"

    DragListItem:
        text: "Test Item 2"

    DragListItem:
        text: "Test Item 3"

    DragListItem:
        text: "Test Item 4"

"""

class DragListItem(DragBehavior, OneLineListItem):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Initially, all widgets are placed in the bottom left-hand corner of the screen. I would like them to be aligned, one after the other, on the middle of the left side of the screen.

Thank you!

EDIT: I should probably make it clear that using a vertically-oriented BoxLayout will not work because I would like them to be able to be side-by-side at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. Instead of using `pos_hint`, one can instead use the `pos` attribute in a way similar to:

```
[...]

DragListItem:
    text: "Item 1"
    pos: root.x + 100, root.y + 100

[...]
```